# How can I know when a series of functions have all finished their exeution in Node js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Here's a code snippet

```
var zip = new require('node-zip')(data, {base64: false, checkCRC32: true});

for (var i in zip.files) {
    fs.writeFile(path.join(to, i), zip.files[i], function(err) {
        if (err) { error = err; }
    });
}
```

Is there any way to be aware of when they're all executed?

Comment: I think the usual method is to set a counter to the number of tasks, and decrement the counter at the end of each task. Run completion code when it hits zero.

Comment: look into promises q library

Answer (score 1):

A very commonly used module for handling many types of asynchronous operations is the [async.js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) module.  In fact, it's the most depended upon module in [NPM](https://www.npmjs.org/) behind underscore.

In your case I recommend the async.series function.

```
var async = require('async');
var zip = new require('node-zip')(data, {base64: false, checkCRC32: true});

async.eachSeries(zip.files, function(file, cb) {
    fs.writeFile(path.join(to, i, file, function(err) {
      if(err) return cb(err);
      cb();
    });
  },
  function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Common problem. Try [each-async](https://github.com/sindresorhus/each-async) which abstracts the counter method so you don't have to write it yourself. You can also look at promises, but that might not work if your code doesn't use promises already; it can be weird to mix promises and callback code.